# how to call Asynktask for list of String inside forloop in android

Tags: android

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = splitFileList;

                for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {

                    tempFileName = splitFileList.get(i);
                    String splitFileCheckinDirectory = splitVideofilepath + Constant.SPLIT_VIDEO + "/" + list1.get(i) + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION;

                    File myfile = new File(splitFileCheckinDirectory);
                    if (!myfile.exists()) {
                        new TrimmVideo(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + getFileNameFromFilePath(mFilePath), mStartTImelist.get(i), mEndTimelist.get(i) - mStartTImelist.get(i)).execute();

                    }
                   }
```

below is my Asynktask which i am trying execute inside for loop

```
private class TrimmVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final String mediaPath;
        private final double endTime;
        private final int length;
        private double startTime;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        private TrimmVideo(String mediaPath, int startTime, int length) {
            this.mediaPath = mediaPath;
            this.startTime = startTime;
            this.length = length;
            this.endTime = this.startTime + this.length;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(VideoPlayActvity.this,
                    "Trimming videos", "Please wait...", true);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            trimVideo();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            dbHandler.updateFlag(fileModel == null ? tempFileName : fileModel.getfilename());
            btn_save_video.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        private void trimVideo() {
            try {
                File file = new File(mediaPath);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                FileChannel in = fis.getChannel();
                Movie movie = MovieCreator.build(in);

                List<Track> tracks = movie.getTracks();
                movie.setTracks(new LinkedList<Track>());

                boolean timeCorrected = false;

                // Here we try to find a track that has sync samples. Since we can only start decoding
                // at such a sample we SHOULD make sure that the start of the new fragment is exactly
                // such a frame
                for (Track track : tracks) {
                    if (track.getSyncSamples() != null && track.getSyncSamples().length > 0) {
                        if (timeCorrected) {
                            // This exception here could be a false positive in case we have multiple tracks
                            // with sync samples at exactly the same positions. E.g. a single movie containing
                            // multiple qualities of the same video (Microsoft Smooth Streaming file)

                            //throw new RuntimeException("The startTime has already been corrected by another track with SyncSample. Not Supported.");
                        } else {
                            startTime = correctTimeToNextSyncSample(track, startTime);
                            timeCorrected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (Track track : tracks) {
                    long currentSample = 0;
                    double currentTime = 0;
                    long startSample = -1;
                    long endSample = -1;

                    for (int i = 0; i < track.getDecodingTimeEntries().size(); i++) {
                        TimeToSampleBox.Entry entry = track.getDecodingTimeEntries().get(i);
                        for (int j = 0; j < entry.getCount(); j++) {
                            // entry.getDelta() is the amount of time the current sample covers.

                            if (currentTime <= startTime) {
                                // current sample is still before the new starttime
                                startSample = currentSample;
                            } else if (currentTime <= endTime) {
                                // current sample is after the new start time and still before the new endtime
                                endSample = currentSample;
                            } else {
                                // current sample is after the end of the cropped video
                                break;
                            }
                            currentTime += (double) entry.getDelta() / (double) track.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
                            currentSample++;
                        }
                    }
                    movie.addTrack(new CroppedTrack(track, startSample, endSample));
                }

                IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);
                File storagePath = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + Constant.SPLIT_VIDEO + "/");
                storagePath.mkdirs();
                File myMovie = new File(storagePath, fileModel == null ? "/" + tempFileName + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION : fileModel.getfilename() + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myMovie);
                FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
                out.getBox(fc);
                dbHandler.updateFlag(fileModel == null ? tempFileName : fileModel.getfilename());
                fc.close();
                fos.close();
                fis.close();
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private double correctTimeToNextSyncSample(Track track, double cutHere) {
            double[] timeOfSyncSamples = new double[track.getSyncSamples().length];
            long currentSample = 0;
            double currentTime = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < track.getDecodingTimeEntries().size(); i++) {
                TimeToSampleBox.Entry entry = track.getDecodingTimeEntries().get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < entry.getCount(); j++) {
                    if (Arrays.binarySearch(track.getSyncSamples(), currentSample + 1) >= 0) {
                        // samples always start with 1 but we start with zero therefore +1
                        timeOfSyncSamples[Arrays.binarySearch(track.getSyncSamples(), currentSample + 1)] = currentTime;
                    }
                    currentTime += (double) entry.getDelta() / (double) track.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
                    currentSample++;
                }
            }
            for (double timeOfSyncSample : timeOfSyncSamples) {
                if (timeOfSyncSample > cutHere) {
                    return timeOfSyncSample;
                }
            }
            return timeOfSyncSamples[timeOfSyncSamples.length - 1];
        }
    }
```

splitFileList list Contain 2 Size data a,b i want to execute synchronously one by one i.e loop start from 0 then it should complete asynk task for 0 then if loop will go one then it should complete please suggest me how to execute asynk task one by one in for loop .

Answer (score 1):

You can't run synchronously by `AsyncTask` You must use thread some thing like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
ArrayList<String> list1 = splitFileList;

            for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {

                tempFileName = splitFileList.get(i);
                String splitFileCheckinDirectory = splitVideofilepath + Constant.SPLIT_VIDEO + "/" + list1.get(i) + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION;

                File myfile = new File(splitFileCheckinDirectory);
                if (!myfile.exists()) {
                    trimVideo(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + getFileNameFromFilePath(mFilePath), mStartTImelist.get(i), mEndTimelist.get(i) - mStartTImelist.get(i)); //here you can run synchronously work
                    }
                 }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
t.start();
try {
    t.join();
.....
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}




 private void trimVideo(String mediaPath, int startTime, int length) {
        try {
            File file = new File(mediaPath);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            FileChannel in = fis.getChannel();
            Movie movie = MovieCreator.build(in);

            List<Track> tracks = movie.getTracks();
            movie.setTracks(new LinkedList<Track>());

            boolean timeCorrected = false;

            // Here we try to find a track that has sync samples. Since we can only start decoding
            // at such a sample we SHOULD make sure that the start of the new fragment is exactly
            // such a frame
            for (Track track : tracks) {
                if (track.getSyncSamples() != null && track.getSyncSamples().length > 0) {
                    if (timeCorrected) {
                        // This exception here could be a false positive in case we have multiple tracks
                        // with sync samples at exactly the same positions. E.g. a single movie containing
                        // multiple qualities of the same video (Microsoft Smooth Streaming file)

                        //throw new RuntimeException("The startTime has already been corrected by another track with SyncSample. Not Supported.");
                    } else {
                        startTime = correctTimeToNextSyncSample(track, startTime);
                        timeCorrected = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (Track track : tracks) {
                long currentSample = 0;
                double currentTime = 0;
                long startSample = -1;
                long endSample = -1;

                for (int i = 0; i < track.getDecodingTimeEntries().size(); i++) {
                    TimeToSampleBox.Entry entry = track.getDecodingTimeEntries().get(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < entry.getCount(); j++) {
                        // entry.getDelta() is the amount of time the current sample covers.

                        if (currentTime <= startTime) {
                            // current sample is still before the new starttime
                            startSample = currentSample;
                        } else if (currentTime <= endTime) {
                            // current sample is after the new start time and still before the new endtime
                            endSample = currentSample;
                        } else {
                            // current sample is after the end of the cropped video
                            break;
                        }
                        currentTime += (double) entry.getDelta() / (double) track.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
                        currentSample++;
                    }
                }
                movie.addTrack(new CroppedTrack(track, startSample, endSample));
            }

            IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);
            File storagePath = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + Constant.SPLIT_VIDEO + "/");
            storagePath.mkdirs();
            File myMovie = new File(storagePath, fileModel == null ? "/" + tempFileName + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION : fileModel.getfilename() + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myMovie);
            FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
            out.getBox(fc);
            dbHandler.updateFlag(fileModel == null ? tempFileName : fileModel.getfilename());
            fc.close();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private double correctTimeToNextSyncSample(Track track, double cutHere) {
        double[] timeOfSyncSamples = new double[track.getSyncSamples().length];
        long currentSample = 0;
        double currentTime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < track.getDecodingTimeEntries().size(); i++) {
            TimeToSampleBox.Entry entry = track.getDecodingTimeEntries().get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < entry.getCount(); j++) {
                if (Arrays.binarySearch(track.getSyncSamples(), currentSample + 1) >= 0) {
                    // samples always start with 1 but we start with zero therefore +1
                    timeOfSyncSamples[Arrays.binarySearch(track.getSyncSamples(), currentSample + 1)] = currentTime;
                }
                currentTime += (double) entry.getDelta() / (double) track.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
                currentSample++;
            }
        }
        for (double timeOfSyncSample : timeOfSyncSamples) {
            if (timeOfSyncSample > cutHere) {
                return timeOfSyncSample;
            }
        }
        return timeOfSyncSamples[timeOfSyncSamples.length - 1];
    }
```

Comment: so u mean to say that we cant use Asynk Task we ll have to Use Thread for this ?we need to create one more method inside there we need to use Thread

Comment: Yes could you try that?

Comment: No can u please help me in this  i am not able to do execute inside thread @Hazem

Comment: Just call your functions into run function

Comment: But i will apply for loop inside that please suggest me. and how i will pass starttime endtime in Thread Constructor i never use such type of thing .

Comment: doWorks inside that we call Asynk Task u mean to say that?

Comment: Inside DoWorks but without AsyncTask you must make normal function insteade asyncTask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152486/discussion-between-adevelopment-and-hazem).

Comment: @Adevelopment do just say NO, it will no gonna help anyone neither you nor who helping you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't implement @Hazem answer you can go with another approach.

For this you need to maintain counter for each of your data and forget about for loop.

First you need to call asynctask for first position of your list.Something like this:

```
if(list1.size() > 0) {
      fileCounter=0;
      tempFileName = splitFileList.get(fileCounter);
      String splitFileCheckinDirectory = splitVideofilepath + Constant.SPLIT_VIDEO + "/" + tempFileName  + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION;

      File myfile = new File(splitFileCheckinDirectory);
      if (!myfile.exists()) {
          new TrimmVideo(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + getFileNameFromFilePath(mFilePath), mStartTImelist.get(i), mEndTimelist.get(i) - mStartTImelist.get(i)).execute();
      }
}
```

Then in onPostExecute of your asyncTask

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            dbHandler.updateFlag(fileModel == null ? tempFileName : fileModel.getfilename());
            btn_save_video.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Update your counter here
            fileCounter++;
            // Check if your incremented counter doesn't exceed your list size
            if(fileCounter < list1.size()) {
                 // Then call your asynctask again with updated counter data
                empFileName = splitFileList.get(fileCounter);
                String splitFileCheckinDirectory = splitVideofilepath + Constant.SPLIT_VIDEO + "/" + tempFileName  + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION;

                File myfile = new File(splitFileCheckinDirectory);
                if (!myfile.exists()) {
                      new TrimmVideo(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + getFileNameFromFilePath(mFilePath), mStartTImelist.get(i), mEndTimelist.get(i) - mStartTImelist.get(i)).execute();
                 }
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help you.